# Without a roadmap, can DLR be used with IronPython, assuming it will continue to be packaged in future .NET Versions

Tags: .net, wpf, numpy, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

DLR or Dynamic Language Runtime hasn't seen any activity after mid 2010, still around its [v1.0 release](http://dlr.codeplex.com/) since then.

I need DLR and IronPython to run my Python code using Numpy and at the same time provide a sleek WPF User Interface.

Comment: You are missing a question. The DLR works and the IronPython team handles updates and fixes (especially) in the context of IronPython.

Comment: DLR is also used by pythonnet, for COM interop, powershell, ASP.NET and provides `dynamic` object for C#. Likely it is going to stay! VB.NET had similar dynamic objects long before DLR.

Comment: As the DLR is being open sourced and thus managed individually by few like IronPython, will update the question when its open for editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off:

> DLR or Dynamic Language Runtime hasn't seen any activity after mid 2010

That's not... entirely accurate. The version you point to is the old codeplex version. Since then IronPython and the DLR have moved to Github. You can find it [here](https://github.com/IronLanguages/). As you will see there have been updates to the DLR as recently as 24 days ago.

Secondly:

> run my Python code using Numpy and at the same time provide a sleek WPF User Interface.

Well, the WPF bindings have been developed pretty far from personal experience. Currently Numpy is not usable with the latest IronPython. (As of Aug 2016), but there has been chat on [their gitter](https://gitter.im/IronLanguages/main) of a move to fix it.

Comment: Inside IronPython, we cannot use the same Numpy package we use in the Normal Python, am I right ?

Comment: Did not get what you meant by _"WPF binding have been developed pretty far from personal experience"_ Do you mean you can't comment about WPF being a sleek experience ?

Comment: Correct, Numpy does not work with the latest IronPython2 release. And WPF is a great UI framework. I really like it. But "sleek experience" is rather subjective and nebulous. What do you mean? Easy to develop with? Looks good? Runs fast?

Comment: So not just Numpy but would 'x' package which works in Python will not work as is, in IronPython, it will be required to be tweaked in someway and maintained ?

Comment: On packages, it depends. Look on Google. On sleek interface, IMO yes, you can with WPF. There are great apps written with WPF.